# C++11 gives error: could not convert but C++14 does not

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, c++17

Why does this code give an error with C++11? With C++ >11, it compiles just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef void (*cmdH)(const char* args, const uint8_t argCnt);

struct CMDList {
    char* cmd = nullptr; /**< @brief Command C-string. */
    cmdH cmdHandler = nullptr; /**< @brief Pointer to command function. See \ref cmdH */
};

CMDList list[2] =
{
    { "test", nullptr },
    { "hello", nullptr }
}; // ERROR HERE
```

> error: could not convert ‘{"test", nullptr}’ from ‘’ to ‘CMDList’

I'm testing my code with https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: `char* cmd` <- Non `const` pointer. `{ "test", nullptr },` `"test"` is `const` data. Technically this hasn't been allowed for a long, long time. Compilers have been getting stricter on whether or not to outright reject it to prevent programmers from blowing their legs off.

Comment: What compiler?  My compiler doesn't accept that for C++98, C++11 or C++14.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. Tried with `const char*` and it does not work.

Comment: Why this is bad: `"test"` is a String Literal. It could be sitting in a read-only chunk of storage and if someone later attempts to modify it, for example, `strtok{list[0].cmd, ' ');`, Ka-BLAM-o. Pray for a crash because it's better than the sorts of weird and unpredictable behaviour you could get.

Comment: To debug the problem you may want to reduce your `struct` to one variable and try it out (after adjusting your array declaration). Then add them back in. I agree with the previous comments that you should use `const char *`. You can also add a constructor to your struct to help initialization

Comment: No one has answered yet, so update the question with a [mre] (MRE) and we'll see what's up pretty fast. Heck, making the MRE will probably reduce the noise around the mistake enough for you to see it yourself. Update the question with the MRE and Self-answer if it does.

Comment: @ChrisSc whole array will be const, so all members will be consts , right?
`const char*` does not work.

Comment: Also make sure that "does not work" means "Got the exact same error in the exact same place". Sucks to have two mistakes and discard a valid fix for one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Problem was with default values in struct declaration.
Also, `char*` should be `const char*`.

```
struct CMDList {
    const char* cmd; /**< @brief Command C-string. */
    cmdH cmdHandler; /**< @brief Pointer to command function. See \ref cmdH */
};
```

Comment: Warning on the *whole array should be `const`* claim. Making a the struct `const` means you can't change the pointer in the struct, but you may still be able to change the data at the pointer.